Do you need Thieves' Tools to pick a lock or disarm a trap?
Under the 2014 rules, it wasn't entirely clear whether you needed Thieves' Tools to pick a lock or disarm a trap.
Now, with the 2024 rules: Does a character need Thieves' Tools to pick a lock or disarm a trap?

Related: Does having proficiency in Sleight of Hand give advantage to Thieves' Tool check to pick a lock?

Yes, for picking a lock, but not always for disarming a trap
According to the rules, you use the Utilize action with your Thieves' Tools to pick a lock or disarm a trap:

Thieves' Tools (25 GP)
Ability: Dexterity
Utilize: Pick a lock (DC 15), or disarm a trap (DC 15)

And then, if you have Thieves' Tools, you make the check with your Sleight of Hand skill. From the PHB, Chapter 6: Equipment, Adventuring Gear (emphasis mine):

Lock (10 GP)
A Lock comes with a key. Without the key, a creature
can use Thieves' Tools to pick this Lock with a successful DC 15
Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check.


Manacles (2 GP)
Each set of Manacles comes with a key. Without the key, a creature can use Thieves' Tools  to pick the Manacles' lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check.

And from the DMG, Chapter 3: DM's Toolbox, Doors (emphasis mine):

Locked Door
Characters who don't have the key to a locked door can try
to pick the lock using Thieves' Tools. [...] the character picks the lock by making a successful Dexterity
(Sleight of Hand) check using Thieves' Tools. [...]

Traps
The same applies to traps, but depending on the specific trap, you may not need to use Thieves' Tools. One example is found in the DMG, Chapter 3: DM's Toolbox, Traps (emphasis mine):

Poisoned Needle
Detect and Disarm. As a Search action, a creature can examine the trapped lock and make a DC 15 Wisdom (Perception) check, detecting the
needle on a successful check. Once the trap is detected, a character
can take an action to try to disarm the trap, doing so with a
successful DC 15 Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check. On a failed check,
the creature triggers the trap.

DM's ruling
As stated in the core rulebooks, you'll need your Thieves' Tools to pick a lock or disarm a trap. If you don't have any, you can improvise other methods with your DM's approval.

It might be worth mentioning that there are more ways to open a lock than picking it. It could be destroyed, e.g.. Using shape water to freeze the lock might destroy it, likewise smashing it. Either way, I think @Nobody might be right that they aren't necessary even to pick the lock.

@nonymous When I wrote the question and then the answer, I was focusing specifically on using Thieves' Tools to pick a lock according to the new 2024 rules (PHB, DMG). Of course, a DM might allow a lock to be destroyed or broken in other ways, but that wasn’t the intent of my question. Additionally, of course a DM can make any ruling and may allow players to improvise different methods to open or break a lock.

The question asks about using thieves tools to disarm a trap, but this answer only addresses one kind of trap, a trapped lock.

@Tarod, Where does it say that Thieves' Tools are necessary? Everything you've cited says that it's possible for a given DC, but the rules are not that restrictive. The beauty of the whole game is the ability to improvise. If I want to pick a lock with a piece of wire, I ought to be able to try, albeit with disadvantage or something.

@nonymous it's stated in the Lock: "... Without the key, a creature can use Thieves' Tools to pick this Lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check." As I mentioned, a DM can allow other methods. I’ll update my answer to reflect that. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Ok. Your question appears to ask about locks in general, but you meant to only ask about the purchasable item Lock for 10 GP?  Maybe updating the question to reflect that is a good idea. Even so, the operative can in the description is not restrictive. It does not say can only, as your answer implies.

Thieves tools always can be used, but are not a must-have
The DMG says

Characters who don't have the key to a locked door can try to pick the lock using Thieves' Tools.

and the Lock equipment says

Without the key, a creature can use Thieves' Tools to pick this Lock with a successful DC 15 Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check.

Both tell you that you can pick locks with Thieves tools, and the skill for it is making a successful Dexterity (Sleight of Hands) check; not that you can only pick locks with Thieves Tools. So with Thieves tools, you always can try to pick the lock - but that does not mean there can not be other ways that allow you to do so, too. This is on page 13, PHB:

The DM has the ultimate say on whether a skill is relevant in a situation.

In an adventuring situation, when the characters find themselves locked up in a dank dungeon with a crude lock, and just the elf's hairpin and a rusty old nail from the bunk in there, a DM would entirely be in his rights to allow them to make a Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) check with those to pick the lock -- maybe at Disadvantage due to circumstances for not having the best tools for the job. Plenty of people in the real world and in movies have picked locks on Handcuffs and such with a pin. Ask Hannibal Lecter. It's a well-used trope and the rules allow this to work if the DM does.
You get advantage if you are proficient in both the tools you use, and the skill you use. That makes it desirable to have someone in the party that is proficient in Slight of Hand and Thieves Tools for the job of picking a lock or disarming a lock with a poison needle. After all, failure with the needle means you get stabbed and poisoned. As it is not a big cost to carry Thieves' Tools, adventuring parties tend to bring some along.
Traps
It is the similar for traps, but here the rules do not tell you that you can always disarm traps using Thieves Tools. The DM decides what skills and tools you may need to disarm any given trap, or if that is not even possible. The DMG tells you that a trapped lock with a poison needle can always be disarmed with Sleight of Hand, without mentioning any specific tools. But for example, a rolling stone trap triggered by a treasure plate would be disarmed using "an Iron Spike or a similar object", or a trip wire can be cut.

Could you consider a hairpin or two an "improvised Thieves' Tool"?  If there is a requirement for a specific tool, you could say you're satisfying it that way, and have disadvantage for a tool that isn't ideal.  (Or for a character who routinely used their hairpins this way, those might be their standard thieves' tools with no disadvantage, since that's what they're used to, especially if they chose those hairpins for their shape and stiffness / springyness.)

@PeterCordes Maybe - the new rules do not list any more what's included or not. In reality, if you have a lock with tumblers, all you need is something to push/wriggle them, another thing to apply torque. Although I’m not sure medieval locks had tumblers already. For modern manacles, all you need is something to slide over the ratchet tooths. Again, medieval ones may have been different. But Thieves Tools cost 25 gp. If you can improvise them with stuff worth a few coppers at best, who‘d by them? I think this is one of the cases where a DM con cover for simplistic rules filling the gaps.

Good point about cost.  But a full set of thieves' tools presumably includes more than just lockpicks, like stuff for disarming traps and jimmying windows (prybars and so on).  And part of the cost might be due to being a specialty item, although in medieval settings where everything is hand-made anyway, economy of scale might not be much of a factor.  Or maybe getting hairpins made of strong and appropriately flexible and springy metal would cost more.

@PeterCordes Yes, thst is exactly the point: you do not need a full set of Thieves Tools to pick s lock. You just need something that allows you to pick a lock.
